# Issue with Integration of a Parameter-Dependent Function in Mathematica

Tags: parametric-functions

The following Mathematica code is given:

```
lambda[n_Integer] := (n - 1/2)^2
eigF[x_, n_Integer] := Sin[x*Sqrt[lambda[n]]]
n1 = Refine[Integrate[(Sin[x*Sqrt[(n - 1/2)^2]])^2, {x, 0, L}], 
  Element[n, Integers]]
n2 = Refine[Integrate[(eigF[x, n])^2, {x, 0, L}], 
  Element[n, Integers]]
```

The `n1` is computed correctly (yielding $\frac{\pi (2 n-1)}{4 n-2}$). However, `n2` results in the input value, that is, `Integrate[eigF[x, n]^2, {x, 0, π}, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Replace `n_Integer` with `n` in your definition of `eigF`, because you need the definition to apply for a _symbolic_ $n$, not only for a numeric, integer $n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Problem solved!